# create dict from list using nested list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list like:
`data = ['a:b', 'c:d', 'e:f', 'g:h']`
from which i have to create dict.

```
xx = [i.split(":") for i in data]
d = {k:v for k,v in xx}
```

this way it works but when i tried to put it in a single line, error comes, too many value to unpack.

```
d = {k:v for i in data for k,v in i.split(":")}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Is it because we cannot add operational statement in right side (like split). Is there any other optimized way for the task?

Comment: Have you tried `dict(el.split(':') for el in data)` ? I'm sure there's a dupe explaining that one...

Comment: yep that worked.
Any specific reason why the mentioned scenario not working?

Comment: What you were trying to write was: `{k:v for k, v in (i.split() for i in data)}`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `for k, v in i.split(":")` because that would only work for an iterable returning pairs of elements (such as [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), for example), and `split()` returns a flat list. You need to use a list comprehension or a generator expression for the `split()` part:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in (i.split(":") for i in data)}
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h'}
```

Or just use the [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor:

```
>>> dict(i.split(":") for i in data)
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h'}
```